# Export data from lotus notes database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I am using a lotus notes database, where our whole company adds its customer data to it. The search function should give me the customer and when I click it I get more detailed information, which I need for my daily work.

However, I have to search this database and it is quite unreliable in terms of displaying the data and also often because of data insertion errors I do not find what I am desiring.

Therefore, I was wondering if I could export this database to excel and search it through with the filters.

Any recommendations how to do that?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: please define "adds data to it" what type of data ? Files? text ? If the data you want to search is in column, you can File/Export to CSV.

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer basically I when I have found the data that I need, I have to click on it and get to a more detailed page of the customer. What I would need is just all customers from the database, with a link besides it that, when you click it opens up the detailed information in lotus notes.

Comment: Lotus Notes has excellent search features. I really can't imagine that you'll be better off in Excel versus just figuring out how to make it work for you. For what you described, adding a view to the database (a private one if you don't have permission to add a public view) should make it very easy to search on customers - if there isn't already a view that does that for you. And if the database is full-text indexed, that would be another easy way to find your customer's.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Thx for your extremely helpful answer! However, in the end I want to give this excel tool to my employees, who are not so keen on lotus notes...

Comment: Well, good luck with that. IMHO, you will end up making life harder for both you and the users. Instead of giving them the tools they need and the opportunity to learn that Lotus Notes is actually a good tool that can easily do exactly what they need, you are giving them something that just reinforces their prejudice against Notes - and will likely be slow, hard to use on a day by day basis, and another piece of unnecessary code to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

You could also utilize the native full-text search of Domino : in the [View] menu, click "Search this view".

Answer (score 1):

Select all the rows you want to export.

Do Edit/Copy AS>Table (could be long)

Past in EXCEL you will also get a link to the document in Excel.

This solution is relevant only if you research in few data. You may also build a "clever" view in Notes (exploding spaces for example) and search "start with" which is alway up to date.

Comment: Thx for our answer! I am using notes 8.5 and do not find the export to excel link. Btw I have basically over 40000 entries I would like to export how to create one of these views?

Comment: don't you have the **menu** EDIT / COPY AS ?

Comment: Found it. However, when doing it I get: `Document has too many paragraphs - it has to be split into multiple documents`. Furthermore, I do not get he full data!

Comment: You can add columns to the view. All the data that you will display in the view will also be "exported" to Excel.

Comment: I am not the admin of the database, only user of it. How would you add columns to the view?

Comment: check if admin/admin gave you right to create a View:
In the view click on **menu** Create / View

Answer (score 1):

I have pulled Notes view information into Excel from the Excel side via VBA - you'd need (to create) a view with all the relevant fields in columns first.  Here's some code that worked for me:  [Accessing Lotus Notes database from Excel VBA - how do I pick up COLUMNVALUES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414967/accessing-lotus-notes-database-from-excel-vba-how-do-i-pick-up-columnvalues)

I was picking up category subtotals..presumably you want the document contents instead so change the

Set Entry = nav.getNextCategory(Entry)
to
Set Entry = nav.getNextDocument(Entry)

and tweak the VBA code to suit which columns you want... good luck !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! My problem is that I do not know the view name? Any recommendation how to show all avaiable one?

Comment: this just worked for me from Excel VBA code                                          -     Sub Notesviews()
    Dim db As Object
    Dim view As Object
    Dim session As Object
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    r = 0
    Set session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 'Start a session to notes
    Call session.Initialize
    Set db = session.getdatabase("MSPreston", "Billbook1415.nsf")
    For Each v In db.views
    Cells(20 + r, 2) = v.Name
    r = r + 1
    Next v
End Sub